# `chrome.tabs.group` is undefined

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to fiddle with chrome tabs, in particular, I want to group them using `chrome.tabs.group`

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-group

However, this function is undefined

Here is my manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "commands": {
    "toggle-pin": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Ctrl+Shift+P" },
      "description": "Test Action"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my `background.js` script

```js
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
  if (command == "toggle-pin") {
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
       // Here i want to use the chrome.tabs.group method, but
       // it is not defined
    })   
  }
})
```

What do I miss?

Comment: It's added in Chrome 88 so I guess you're still on 87.

Comment: @wOxxOm .. you are right. That was the problem, Thxs

Comment: @wOxxOm Hi, what should I update in order to use this method? Or it is something I must wait for release to use?

Answer (score 2):

As @wOxxOm pointed out, this feature is only available in Chrome 88 (which is in beta right now 12 Dec 2020)